# How a add a new widget inside a widget which is dynamically created using jquery for gridstack in an Angular6 Project

Tags: jquery, angular, gridstack

I have a button on which I have added a click event , in that method I am generating a new grid-stack widget

```
AddWidget(fieldType) 

{
   var templateString;
   switch(fieldType) 
   {
      case 'Text' :
                    <div class="grid-stack-item-content" id="" style="background-color: #18bc9c">
                        <button class="fa fa-ellipsis-v buttonClicked" style="float:right;border:none;background-color: transparent;margin-right:2px;"></button>
                        <div class="ms-TextField" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                             <label class="ms-Label ">
                                Field Name
                             </label>
                             <input class="ms-TextField-field updateValue" style="width:75%" type="text" placeholder="Enter Field Name">
                       </div>
                  </div>
          break; 
   }
}
```

After that,

```
    var $htmlString = $(templateString);
    $htmlString.children('div.grid-stack-item-content').attr('id', newid);
    var grids = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack');
    grids.addWidget($htmlString, 1, 1, 3, 1, true, 3);
```

This works fine, But I am blocked how to again add a new widget inside this newwly created widget.

Suppose I am having a button in the above created widget, and I need to add a further sub grid-stack-item widget inside it.

How to solve this problem??

Comment: Try the solution without jquery. Angular can do much more than jquery.

Comment: But, then how to use gridstack.js in it , since it's a jquery plugin,
I need to use drag and drop behaviour of gridstack

Comment: Have you checked out primeng ?? It has some great components ? And to fix your problem may be create on reusable component and try to stack that instead if its the code for new widget.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but its a compulsion I have to use gridstack or something similar to it which provides drag and drop functionality